# Azure doesn´t allow to add a TFS existing account

Tags: azure, tfs

[image]Maybe someone could help me here...

I´m using old version of azure portal, trying to add my TFS online account.
On the URL combobox, It continuously says "URL: (Excluded) mytfs".
And doesn´t allow me to add it on the "fast creation" option.

How can I change this situation of "Excluded" of my tfs site?

Thanks.

UPDATED:
Screenshot of the problem, as you can see it says (Excluded) and i can´t take it of that state.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot so that we can better understand the issue?

Comment: Done, i believed i have no privileges to upload photos, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I get the answer by myself, by pure coincidence.

I configured Active Directory to my tfs account and it started working after that.

Now I can use tfs and my sites.
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the subscription you selected if you have more than one. I had the same issue and it turned out that I selected wrong subscription.

Otherwise check if TFS admin email is added to Administrators in Azure.

Comment: My tfs user is the same than azure user. How can i check what you say about subscription?

Comment: There is 'Subscriptions' link at the top. Click it and open 'Filter by directory' dropdown. If there's more than one subscription there try selecting others and see if it helps